# WildFly 9 send email twice

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-mail, wildfly, ejb-3.1

I have a little trouble.
I configured mail session on wildfly 9.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
        <mail-session name="AppSrvMail" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/AppSrvMail">
            <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp" ssl="false" username="app-srv@example.com" password="example"/>
        </mail-session>
    </subsystem>
```

...

```
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="host.example.com" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
```

after that i inject in stateless bean resource:

```
@Resource(name = "java:jboss/mail/AppSrvMail")
private Session session;
```

and method:

```
@Override
public void send(String address, String topic, String textMessage) {
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("app-srv@example.com"));
        Address toAddress = new InternetAddress(address);
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
        message.setSubject(topic);
        message.setContent(textMessage, CONTENT_TYPE_HTML);
        Transport.send(message);

        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        LOG.log("Cannot send mail", e);
    }
}
```

After that all right, code is working, **but** all receivers that i send have double messages. Exactly, wilfly send the same email twice.
If i connecting this account in to client (for example, evolution client in linux) and send message - receiver get one message, it's ok.
Someone know's what's goin on?
 
Please, help me.

Comment: This post was useful in finding the relevant code/section for emails. Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `send()` method contains a duplicate line:

```
Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: oh my GOD.... yes, it is!! I was very overworked and did not see the banal error. I feel ashamed.